# How to replace a value from the joined tables if it is present in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am working on sqlserver. I have three tables, TableA, TableB and TableMain, with Date, StartTime and FinishTime columns. These three tables can be joined by the common CustomerID. Unfortunately the TableMain has day_of_week while the other two have date. I have to query by the date, day_of_week and the customerid. In the sql given below I am using the date 2016-10-14, which corresponds to Saturday. The SQL I have used is given below. However he SQL doesn't compile. I am getting "Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'as'" error.

**TableA**:

```
CustomerID  Date        StartTime
100         10/14/2016  11:00 AM
100         10/16/2016  10:00 AM
101         10/18/2016  11:30 AM
```

**TableB**:

```
CustomerID  Date        FinishTime
100         10/15/2016  3:00 PM
101         10/16/2016  4:00 PM
102         10/17/2016  6:30 PM
102         10/18/2016  5:00 PM
```

**TableMain**:

```
CustomerID  Day_of_week         StartTime   FinishTime
100         Monday              8:00 AM     10:00 PM
100         Tuesday             8:00 AM     10:00 PM
100         Wednesday           8:00 AM     10:00 PM
100         Thursday            8:00 AM     10:00 PM
100         Friday              8:00 AM     10:00 PM
100         Saturday            8:00 AM     10:00 PM
```

Expected output:

```
CustomerID  Day_of_the_week         StartTime   FinishTime
100         Saturday                11:00 AM    10:00 PM
```

The sql I have so far:

```
 select 
     t.StartTime, t.FinishTime, t.CustomerID 
 from 
     (select
          tm.CustomerID as CustomerID,
          case 
             when tb.FinishTime is not null 
                then tb.FinishTime 
                else tm.FinishTime         
          as FinishTime,
          case 
             when ta.StartTime is not null 
                then ta.StartTime  
                else tm.StartTime 
          as StartTime,
      from 
          TableMain tm
      left join 
          TableB tb on tm.CustomerID = tb.CustomerID
      left join 
          TableA ta on tm.CustomerID = ta.CustomerID 
      where 
          tm.day_of_week = 'SATURDAY' 
          and tb.Date = '2016-10-14' 
          and ta.Date = '2016-10-14') t
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have missed to add `END` to both the `CASE` statements

```
Select 
.........
CASE
    WHEN tb.FinishTime IS NOT NULL THEN tb.FinishTime
    ELSE tm.FinishTime
END  AS FinishTime, --Here
CASE
    WHEN ta.StartTime IS NOT NULL THEN ta.StartTime
    ELSE tm.StartTime
END  AS StartTime --Here & remove the comma
.........
```

But it can be simplified using `COALESCE`, it will return the first `NOT NULL` value from the column list.

```
COALESCE(tb.FinishTime, tm.FinishTime) AS FinishTime,
COALESCE(ta.StartTime, tm.StartTime) AS StartTime
```

Another *logical* mistake was you are filtering the `Left table` column in `Where` clause which *implicitly* converts the `LEFT JOIN` to `INNER JOIN`. Here is the correct query

```
SELECT tm.CustomerID                          AS CustomerID,
       COALESCE(tb.FinishTime, tm.FinishTime) AS FinishTime,
       COALESCE(ta.StartTime, tm.StartTime)  AS StartTime
FROM   TableMain tm
       LEFT JOIN TableB tb
              ON tm.CustomerID = tb.CustomerID
                 AND tb.Date = '2016-10-14'
       LEFT JOIN TableA ta
              ON tm.CustomerID = ta.CustomerID
                 AND ta.Date = '2016-10-14'
WHERE  tm.day_of_week = 'SATURDAY'
```

Comment: Thank you so much! It worked like a charm. Also, thanks a lot for explaining the logic behind it, which helped me a lot!!